# public virtual enum (Dictionary) HOW?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

**SEE BELOW FOR SOLUTION BASED ON ANSWER/COMMENT from @Bertrand Le Roy**

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Not sure how to explain my problem.

I have a Part record in Orchard:

```
    [Display(Name = "Would you like us to call you to discuss the quote for your case?")]
    public ContactClientList ContactClient
    {
        get { return Record.ContactClient; }
        set { Record.ContactClient = value; }
    }
    public enum ContactClientList
    {
        ContactClient_Yes,
        ContactClient_No
    }
    public class ContactClientDictionary
    {
        public static readonly Dictionary<ContactClientList, string> contactclientDictionary = new Dictionary<ContactClientList, string>
        {
            { ContactClientList.ContactClient_No, "No, please do not contact me by telephone." },
            { ContactClientList.ContactClient_Yes, "Yes, please contact me as soon as possibly by telephone to discuss my Uncontested Divorce quote." },
        };
        static string ConvertContactClient(ContactClientList contactclientlist)
        {
            string name;
            return (contactclientDictionary.TryGetValue(contactclientlist, out name))
                ? name : contactclientlist.ToString();
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertContactClient(ContactClientList.ContactClient_Yes));
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertContactClient(ContactClientList.ContactClient_No));
        }
    }
```

Now, I have a  Part Record:

```
public virtual ContactClientList ContactClient { get; set; }
```

And I am getting the error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'ContactClientList' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Any thoughts?

---

**SOLUTION:**

I took out

```
    public enum ContactClientList
    {
        ContactClient_Yes,
        ContactClient_No
    }
    public class ContactClientDictionary
    {
        public static readonly Dictionary<ContactClientList, string> contactclientDictionary = new Dictionary<ContactClientList, string>
        {
            { ContactClientList.ContactClient_No, "No, please do not contact me by telephone." },
            { ContactClientList.ContactClient_Yes, "Yes, please contact me as soon as possibly by telephone to discuss my Uncontested Divorce quote." },
        };
        static string ConvertContactClient(ContactClientList contactclientlist)
        {
            string name;
            return (contactclientDictionary.TryGetValue(contactclientlist, out name))
                ? name : contactclientlist.ToString();
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertContactClient(ContactClientList.ContactClient_Yes));
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertContactClient(ContactClientList.ContactClient_No));
        }
    }
```

from

```
public class ModelNamePart : ContentPart<ModelNamePartRecord 
{
    public ContactClientList ContactClient
    {
        ...
    }
[TOOK OUT FROM HERE]
}
```

And made it it's own class at the end of the ModelNamePartRecord.cs file, but had to change the class name (simply added "Enum" after) and associate it with ContentPartRecord (otherwise it throws an NHibernate association from table unmapped error):

```
public class ContactClientListEnum : ContentPartRecord
{
    public enum ContactClientList
    {
        ...
    }
    public class ContactClientDictionary
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, in the ModelNamePartRecord.cs file, I just updated the class name:

```
public class ModelNamePartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual ContactClientListEnum ContactClient { get; set; }
}
```

AGAIN, the replacement occurs after this portion above in its own class.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the content of your first snippet coming from one file? If not can you update your post where the parts are coming form (which files, which namespaces)?

Comment: Two separate files: a Part.cs and a RecordPart.cs. Both files are in the same folder (/Models) and namespace. So it looks 'namespace ModuleNamespace.Models {} '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are in different modules, you need a reference to the one where the enum is defined added to the project for the module where the record is. If that is already the case, you are probably just missing a using statement on top of the cs file.

Comment: It is located within the same Module, under the Models Folder. It is under the same Module.Models namespace.

Comment: Oh wait, the code you published can't be right: you have a property definition at the same level as the enum and class definition.

Comment: Marking as answer. Your comment led me in the right direction. Check original question under "SOLUTION" section to see how I fixed this problem.